Animate image in LazyVerticalGrid in bottom sheet to full screen image preview
I have a dialogue that has a button to open bottom sheet in that bottom sheet I have an image picker that first item of it is camera preview I want to make this preview full screen when I tap on it.
this is my bottom sheet:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable

fun BottomSheetImagePicker(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
val context = LocalContext.current
val imageUris = getAllImageUris(context)
val selected = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

ModalBottomSheet(onDismiss) {

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3), // 3 columns
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
            CameraPreviewScreen(selected = selected.value) {
                selected.value = true
            }


        }
        item() {
            Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
                ImageItem(imageUris[0])
                ImageItem(imageUris[1])
            }
        }
        val otherImages = imageUris.drop(2)
        items(otherImages) { uri ->
            ImageItem(uri)


        }
    }
}

}
I tried to make CameraPreviewScreen bigger with changing its size and scale but it put camera under other items like this:

now my question is how I can bring it on top of other things in first layer?
I want to make an image picker like telegram there

This is not that hard to implement with SharedElementTransition api except when you use ModalBottomSheet because it's a Dialog, and creates a new window layout and draws above anything on screen. If you try to have shared element transition it crashes with exception with

E FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: layouts
are not part of the same hierarchy

There are 2 ways to implement this with shared transitions, one without and another with ModalBottomSheet to create another Dialog and do shared element transitions in it with a workaround by getting bounds and resource of clicked Image and doing transition in new Dialog.
Telegram also doesn't use a Dialog but a custom scrollable that does snap in specific positions and change TopAppbar.
Using non-Dialog drawer component(Not ModalBottomSheet)

You can substitute custom Composable if you don't want to implement it yourself with BottomSheetScaffold, my initial choice was BottomDrawer but it crashes inside SharedTransitionLayout, when it's fixed you can use it instead of BottomSheetScaffold.
@Preview
@Composable
private fun SharedElementsample() {

    SharedTransitionLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "home",
        ) {
            composable("home") {
                BottomSheetImagePicker(
                    sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout,
                    animatedContentScope = this@composable,
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate("details/$it")
                    },
                    onDismiss = {}
                )
            }

            composable(
                "details/{item}",
                arguments = listOf(navArgument("item") { type = NavType.IntType })
            ) { backStackEntry ->
                val item = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("item") ?: 0
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Black),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(item),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .sharedElement(
                                state = rememberSharedContentState(key = item),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = this@composable,
                            )
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        alignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun BottomSheetImagePicker(
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    animatedContentScope: AnimatedContentScope,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    onClick: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
    val imageUris = remember {
        listOf(
            R.drawable.landscape1,
            R.drawable.landscape2,
            R.drawable.landscape3,
            R.drawable.landscape4,
            R.drawable.landscape5,
            R.drawable.landscape6,
            R.drawable.landscape7,
            R.drawable.landscape8,
            R.drawable.landscape9,
            R.drawable.landscape10
        )
    }

    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
            initialValue = SheetValue.Hidden,
            skipHiddenState = false
        )
    )

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetPeekHeight = 400.dp,
        content = {

            val bottomState = scaffoldState.bottomSheetState
            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)
            ) {

                Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))

                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            bottomState.partialExpand()
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Expand")
                }
            }
            if (bottomState.isVisible) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = .3f))
                )

            }
        },
        sheetContent = {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(3), // 3 columns
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp)
            ) {
                item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(200.dp)
                            .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                    )
                }

                item {

                    Column(
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement
                            .spacedBy(8.dp)
                    ) {
                        ImageItem(
                            sharedTransitionScope,
                            animatedContentScope,
                            imageUris[0],
                            onClick
                        )
                        ImageItem(
                            sharedTransitionScope,
                            animatedContentScope,
                            imageUris[1],
                            onClick
                        )
                    }
                }

                val otherImages = imageUris.drop(2)
                items(otherImages) { uri ->
                    ImageItem(
                        sharedTransitionScope,
                        animatedContentScope,
                        uri,
                        onClick
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
private fun ImageItem(
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    animatedContentScope: AnimatedContentScope,
    @DrawableRes uri: Int,
    onClick: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
    with(sharedTransitionScope) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.sharedElement(
                state = rememberSharedContentState(key = uri),
                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedContentScope,
                boundsTransform = gridBoundsTransform
            ).clickable {
                onClick(uri)
            },
            painter = painterResource(uri),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}

val gridBoundsTransform = BoundsTransform { initialBounds, targetBounds ->
    keyframes {
        durationMillis = 500
        initialBounds at 0 using ArcMode.ArcBelow using FastOutSlowInEasing
        targetBounds at 500
    }
}

 Using another Dialog to draw above ModalBottomSheet
To way to implement this with ModalBottomSheet is to use another Dialog to draw above ModalBottomSheet.

Modal bottom sheets are used as an alternative to inline menus or
simple dialogs on mobile, especially when offering a long list of
action items, or when items require longer descriptions and icons.
Like dialogs, modal bottom sheets appear in front of app content,
disabling all other app functionality when they appear, and remaining
on screen until confirmed, dismissed, or a required action has been
taken.

With this approach you need to handle position and size of image as Rect you get from onGloballyPositioned and  back press as well as in answer below.
private sealed class AnimationScreen {
    data object List : AnimationScreen()
    data class Details(val item: Int, val rect: Rect) : AnimationScreen()
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun SharedElementsample2() {

    BottomSheetImagePicker()
}

@Composable
fun BottomSheetImagePicker() {

    var state by remember {
        mutableStateOf<AnimationScreen>(AnimationScreen.List)
    }

    var openBottomSheet by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()

    // App Content
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = {
                openBottomSheet = openBottomSheet.not()
            }
        ) {
            Text("Expand")
        }
    }

    if (openBottomSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            sheetState = bottomSheetState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().systemBarsPadding(),
            onDismissRequest = {
                openBottomSheet = false
            }
        ) {
            BottomSheetPickerContent { uri, rect ->
                state = AnimationScreen.Details(uri, rect)
            }
        }
    }

    if (state is AnimationScreen.Details) {
        BasicAlertDialog(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Black),
            onDismissRequest = {
                state = AnimationScreen.List
            },
            properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
        ) {

            var visible by remember {
                mutableStateOf(false)
            }

            var expanded by remember {
                mutableStateOf(false)
            }

            val dispatcher = LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current

            BackHandler(visible) {
                visible = false
            }

            SharedTransitionLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    awaitFrame()
                    visible = true
                }

                AnimatedContent(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    targetState = visible,
                    label = "",
                ) { visibleState ->

                    if (expanded.not()) {
                        expanded = visibleState && isTransitionActive.not()
                    }

                    val item = (state as? AnimationScreen.Details)?.item ?: R.drawable.landscape2
                    val rect = (state as? AnimationScreen.Details)?.rect ?: Rect.Zero

                    if (visibleState) {
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                        ) {
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(item),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .sharedElement(
                                        state = rememberSharedContentState(key = item),
                                        animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent,
                                        boundsTransform = gridBoundsTransform
                                    )
                                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        }
                    } else {

                        LaunchedEffect(expanded, isTransitionActive) {
                            if (expanded && isTransitionActive.not()) {
                                dispatcher?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()
                            }
                        }

                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                            val density = LocalDensity.current
                            val width: Dp
                            val height: Dp

                            with(density) {
                                width = rect.width.toDp()
                                height = rect.height.toDp()
                            }
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(item),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .offset {
                                        rect.topLeft.round()
                                    }
                                    .size(width, height)
                                    .sharedElement(
                                        state = rememberSharedContentState(key = item),
                                        animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent,
                                        boundsTransform = gridBoundsTransform
                                    ),
                                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}

@Composable
private fun BottomSheetPickerContent(
    onClick: (Int, Rect) -> Unit,
) {

    val imageUris = remember {
        listOf(
            R.drawable.landscape1,
            R.drawable.landscape2,
            R.drawable.landscape3,
            R.drawable.landscape4,
            R.drawable.landscape5,
            R.drawable.landscape6,
            R.drawable.landscape7,
            R.drawable.landscape8,
            R.drawable.landscape9,
            R.drawable.landscape10
        )
    }

    val imageMap = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf<Int, Rect>()
    }

    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val statusBarHeight = WindowInsets.statusBars.getTop(density)

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3), // 3 columns
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp)
    ) {
        item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(200.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            )
        }

        item {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                ImageItem(
                    modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                        imageMap[imageUris[0]] = Rect(
                            offset = Offset(
                                x = it.positionOnScreen().x,
                                y = it.positionOnScreen().y - statusBarHeight
                            ),
                            size = it.size.toSize()
                        )
                    },
                    uri = imageUris[0],
                    onClick = {
                        onClick(imageUris[0], imageMap[imageUris[0]] ?: Rect.Zero)
                    }
                )
                ImageItem(
                    modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                        imageMap[imageUris[1]] = Rect(
                            offset = Offset(
                                x = it.positionOnScreen().x,
                                y = it.positionOnScreen().y - statusBarHeight
                            ),
                            size = it.size.toSize()
                        )
                    },
                    uri = imageUris[1],
                    onClick = {
                        onClick(imageUris[1], imageMap[imageUris[1]] ?: Rect.Zero)

                    }
                )
            }
        }

        val otherImages = imageUris.drop(2)
        items(otherImages) { uri ->
            ImageItem(
                modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                    imageMap[uri] = Rect(
                        offset = Offset(
                            x = it.positionOnScreen().x,
                            y = it.positionOnScreen().y - statusBarHeight
                        ),
                        size = it.size.toSize()
                    )
                },
                uri = uri,
                onClick = {
                    onClick(uri, imageMap[uri] ?: Rect.Zero)

                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ImageItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @DrawableRes uri: Int,
    onClick: (Int) -> Unit,
) {

    Image(
        modifier = modifier
            .clickable {
                onClick(uri)
            },
        painter = painterResource(uri),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}

