Swipe Image effect in Jetpack compose
I'm creating a social app by Jetpack compose, I referencing some more social app and I see a effect in facebook, user tap a image to preview and can swipe image every way to close preview image
How can I do that effect or maybe give me a tip on a keyword to research this problem?


You can do it with SharedTransitionElementApi or manually by getting position via onGloasballyPositioned/onPlaced. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79223089/animate-image-in-lazyverticalgrid-in-bottom-sheet-to-full-screen-image-preview/79226840#79226840 this one has examples for both. And this one is doing it manually only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77971100/jetpack-compose-how-to-use-a-value-animation-to-directly-control-other-animati/77972956#77972956.

And there are several samples in this link for observing different properties of SharedElementTransition. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/tree/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter9_animation

@Thracian thank you very much , this is what I need
